# I want to return the number of rows it's been since a value occurred

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Alright, I'm starting over with a new bit of code that feels more efficient and shows that I can get some of what I want but not the final bit. Here is the edited code:

```
SELECT
    uq1.UserID,
    uq1.QuestionID,
    r.LastAttempt,
    r.Score,
    r.DateSeen,
    s.LastBad,
    s.Score AS ScoreUnder,
    s.DateSeen AS DateScoreUnder
FROM
    users_questions uq1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        uq2.QuestionID,
        uq2.UserID,
        MAX(UsersQuestionsID) LastAttempt,
        uq2.Score,
        uq2.DateSeen
    FROM
        users_questions uq2
    GROUP BY
        uq2.UserID,
        uq2.QuestionID
) AS r ON r.QuestionID = uq1.QuestionID AND r.UserID = uq1.UserID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        uq3.QuestionID,
        uq3.UserID,
        MAX(UsersQuestionsID) LastBad,
        uq3.Score,
        uq3.DateSeen
    FROM
        users_questions uq3
    WHERE
        uq3.Score <= 250
    GROUP BY
        uq3.UserID,
        uq3.QuestionID
) AS s ON s.QuestionID = uq1.QuestionID AND s.UserID = uq1.UserID
GROUP BY
    uq1.UserID,
    uq1.QuestionID
```

It seems to be more efficient and produce some of what I want. The thing I need to find is the number of iterations between the record that it displays on the last LEFT JOIN and the end of the table for each question and user combo.

My test data is this:

| UsersQuestionsID | Score | DateSeen | UserID | QuestionID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 877 | 2022-06-25 19:51:18 | 14 | 98 |
| 2 | 765 | 2022-06-25 15:52:42 | 14 | 99 |
| 3 | 345 | 2022-06-25 15:54:22 | 14 | 99 |
| 4 | 754 | 2022-06-25 15:54:22 | 14 | 107 |
| 5 | 222 | 2022-06-25 16:11:40 | 13 | 73 |
| 6 | 525 | 2022-06-25 16:11:40 | 13 | 55 |
| 7 | 23 | 2022-06-25 16:11:40 | 13 | 130 |
| 8 | 888 | 2022-06-25 16:11:40 | 13 | 104 |
| 9 | 234 | 2022-07-01 12:41:44 | 14 | 94 |
| 10 | 564 | 2022-07-01 12:41:44 | 14 | 106 |
| 11 | 0 | 2022-07-01 13:59:37 | 14 | 99 |
| 12 | 267 | 2022-07-01 16:57:40 | 14 | 99 |
| 13 | 345 | 2022-07-02 15:17:03 | 13 | 99 |
| 14 | 49 | 2022-07-02 17:44:19 | 14 | 99 |
| 15 | 222 | 2022-07-02 18:10:17 | 14 | 99 |
| 16 | 49 | 2022-07-02 18:10:43 | 14 | 94 |
| 17 | 1000 | 2022-07-02 18:11:18 | 14 | 106 |
| 18 | 0 | 2022-07-06 14:18:51 | 14 | 94 |

Comment: If you need to know how the table is set up containing the base questions, I can post it, but I felt it was relatively useless to waste more space on it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `MAX(uq4.DateSeen)` rather than `MAX(uq4.UsersQuestionID)`?

Comment: I just tried that and it still gives me the same result as above. As you might be able to see, the ExposuresSinceLastZero column is throwing an erroneous answer at the first row since the last time a zero answer occurred was the last time it was answered. This gets even worse if I change uq4.Score = 0 to uq4.score <= (some number here).

Comment: This is a really complex query. Can you simplify it to just the part that's giving you trouble?

Comment: If you use `MAX(uq4.DateSeen)` you need to also change `WHERE uq3.UsersQuestionsID >` to `WHERE uq3.DateSeen >`

Comment: What should the count be if they have no scores under 50? All of UserId 13's scores are higher.

Comment: The bottom line is that I need to find how many instances of the question have been answered since the last time a score for the question was under 250 and if they have never answered a question with less than 250, to output the total number of times the question has been answered

Comment: I was working on this last night but struggling to get something that worked properly. To handle the case of no score under 250 it will need to use `IFNULL()` to provide a default starting date earlier than any existing date, since `MAX(DateSeen)` will be `NULL`.

Comment: Edited and Revamped code. I think this will be easier now.